# Best practice for dealing with different client time zones?

Tags: datetime, timezone, timestamp, client-server

I'm building an iPhone chat app, that uses a central server.
What is the best practice for dealing with different clients time zones?

I mean when client1 sends a message to client2, the server save the message in his database with timestamp according to the servers time zone, that could be different from client1 time zone and client2 time zone..
So how do I manage this so when client2 get the message he will know how to convert it to its time zone, or maybe the server will do the converting??

Answer (score 1):

First you need to store the time as UTC. Then when displayed, you need to detect the timezone and it will add/minus.

Comment: So I need to detect the time zone in client and use it to convert the UTC time I got from the server to local time? Do you know how to do that in objective c ?

Comment: See the documentation for NSDate, NSDateComponents, and NSDateFormatter.
// get current date/time
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
// display in 12HR/24HR (i.e. 11:25PM or 23:25) format according to User Settings
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
NSString *currentTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"User's current time in their preference format:%@",currentTime);

Comment: What if i use timeIntervalSince1970 instead of UTC ? will this work? I don't really understand the differences between this two..